# Ransack with sort_link for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, ransack

I have setup a nested resource like `/projects/1/tasks` and want to use `sort_link` method.

With `<%= sort_link @search, :taskname %>` i expect `/projects/1/tasks?q...` but i do get `/tasks?q...`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass options to the `sort_link` helper, for example

```
sort_link @search, :taskname, { :controller => tasks, action: "index", project_id: @project.id }
```

where `options` can be anything that is accepted by the `url_for` helper

see: https://github.com/ernie/ransack/blob/v0.6.0/lib/ransack/helpers/form_helper.rb

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what i want.